# Box2d Static Bodies Jitter

Tags: javascript, box2d

This is the problem:

http://youtu.be/vxtUDy3I09c

The video speaks for itself.

I don't know what else to call it other than jitter. The static bodies aren't holding up to the dynamic bodies. They "dip" into the static bodies just a little. How do I fix this problem?

```
 density = 1
 friction = 0.5
 restitution = .2
```

Comment: My first guess would be to double-check that the polygon windings are counter-clockwise. Can we assume that the shapes are just sitting there and only affected by gravity? How many position iterations and velocity iterations per time step are you using?

Comment: 10 and 10. Ill check the verts again.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: btw the video is not viewable anymore